# Free online data storage for my bookstore web app in Grails

Tags: data-storage

I'm developing an online free e-book sharing website and I want to use a free online data storage system (may be Google Drive or Dropbox or Box) to store the books uploaded and I want to be able to view and download the documents.

How can I access the storage programatically from my Grails-based web application?

Comment: @reto I used the ruby-on-rails tag to get more responses from the huge community. I want to know how to implement the file access and storage using a free data storage system. But now, I removed the tag.

Comment: Why are people just down voting on this question? SERIOUSLY?!!!

Comment: Don't take this personal. One reason might be that according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" your search for a favorite data storage solution is considered off topic.

Comment: spam? offtopic.... more text needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following helps which provide clear guides on how to implement the datastore integration with my app.

1. [Google Drive Web APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/)
2. [Dropbox - Using the Core API in Java](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java)

One comparison of Google Drive and Dropbox can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AOXICrKXUg&spfreload=10)

If anyone has more resources with more free storage space (greater than 15GB), please share.